# The problem is that my VS code can't update

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio-code

After I log into my VSCode, the VSCode is automatically updated, and after it tells me to restart it, I click "restart for update". It closes and immediately gives the error:

"Failed to install VSCode update"
"Updates may fail due to anti-virus software and/or runaway progress, Please try restarting your machine brfore attempting to update again"
"Please read the log file for more information"
"C:\User\Bla\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-inno-updater-1706808930.log"

And after this message, another window appears with the error:

"Createprocess: code 2 failed"
"The specified file could not be found"

I tried rebooting/turning it off and on again, thinking it would help, but nothing changes.

Comment: 1. Check free disk space.  2. Try to temporary disable antivirus.

Comment: so? the suggested instructions are quite clear. what anti-virus do you hve installed? what do you see in that log file? show us.

Answer (score 0):

Check your free space disk, if this don't solve then you need to update your system to a glibc 2.28 compatible version, but if you can't do that, you can just simply stay on 1.85.2 VSCode version. This problem is on discussion on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203375) and you can check the suggested solution on [VSCode Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq#_can-i-run-vs-code-server-on-older-linux-distributions)

Answer (score 0):

> **Updates may fail due to anti-virus software and/or runaway progress, Please try restarting your machine brfore attempting to update again**

Turn off your anti-virus software and try again.

Or try [uninstalling it completely](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall) and reinstalling the [latest version](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_86).

Answer (score -1):

If checking your free disk space and updating your system to a compatible version don't solve the issue, you can try manually downloading and installing the latest version of VSCode from the official website. You can also try disabling any antivirus software temporarily before attempting the update again.

Another possible solution is to delete the current version of VSCode and then download and install the latest version.

If none of these solutions work, you can check the log file at C:\User\Bla\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-inno-updater-1706808930.log for more information on what went wrong during the update process.